# How can I correct for a slow scanning document feeder?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, image-processing

We've got a HP all-in-one OfficeJet and I find that the document feeder on it is a bit slow, so all the scans come out a bit stretched. Everything we feed into this is A4 which should have an aspect of 1.4142 but actually comes out at 1.64.

Given a multi-page PDF, does anybody know something that I can process it with that can tick the following boxes:

- Shorten the page height as required.
- Preserve the quality (some will be lost, but most should remain)
- Keep the format as a PDF.

I'm trying `convert` (part of ImageMagick) but I'm struggling to get it to do either of the first two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this with some `-resample`:

```
convert -strip -resample 300x260 -density 300 in.pdf -compress jpeg out.pdf
```

The `-compress` flag is in there because without it there was a sevenfold increase in file size. This is slightly smaller than the original with plenty of quality.